# Cannot change language for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, localization

I originally set up both English and Japanese for all Google application as my understandable languages but since it started bothering me I deleted the Japanese and keep only English. However, every time I open Google map, it's in Japanese. I change the language from the setting, but again, next time, it's in Japanese. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change language preference in regional settings here: **[https://www.google.com/preferences1](https://www.google.com/preferences?prev=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fmaps%2F%4048.1535664%2C17.1851188%2C15z#region)** or here: **[https://www.google.com/preferences2](https://www.google.com/preferences?prev=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fmaps%2F%4048.1535664%2C17.1851188%2C15z#languages)**

Comment: It works now! Thank you so much. How many language settings I need to change though...